# schtasks not run the script

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

in powershell (administrator or not) `C:\Users\mine\Desktop\LOL\test.ps1` works properly without the `schtasks`, but when I create `schtasks` with it, it's not working. Nothing happened.

`test.ps1` can run properly in powershell. 
When I query `schtasks`, "Backup DB" is appear the status is ready. 
Let's say I set it `10:08`. 
When I query before `10:08` the next run time is today `10:08`. 
When I query after `10:08` the next run time is tomorrow `10:08`,
but nothing happened in between.

```
PS C:\Users\mine> Schtasks /create /tn "Backup DB" /sc daily /st 10:08 /tr "C:\Users\mine\Desktop\LOL\test.ps1"
WARNING: The task name "Backup DB" already exists. Do you want to replace it (Y/N)? y
SUCCESS: The scheduled task "Backup DB" has successfully been created.
```

In brief, I want to run my `test.ps1` daily using powershell

Comment: Create it normally, program is `powershell.exe` and argument is `-File C:\Users\mine\Desktop\LOL\test.ps1`

Comment: @Drew still nothing happened. i have no idea whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your task creation is fine. Because of you are not calling the powershell.exe to invoke the .ps1, it is technically invoking only .ps1 like a notepad file.

```
                $TaskName = "Backup DB"
                $TaskDescr = "Automated Backup DB"
                $TaskCommand = "c:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
                $TaskScript = '"C:\Users\mine\Desktop\LOL\test.ps1"+'"'
                $TaskArg = "-Executionpolicy unrestricted -file $TaskScript"


                        $service = new-object -ComObject("Schedule.Service")
                        # connect to the local machine.

                        $service.Connect()
                        $rootFolder = $service.GetFolder("\")
                        $TaskDefinition = $service.NewTask(0)
                        $TaskDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Description = "$TaskDescr"
                        $TaskDefinition.Settings.Enabled = $true
                        $TaskDefinition.Settings.AllowDemandStart = $true
                        $TaskDefinition.Settings.StartWhenAvailable = $true
                        $TaskDefinition.Settings.StopIfGoingOnBatteries=$false
                        $TaskDefinition.Settings.DisallowStartIfOnBatteries=$false
                        $TaskDefinition.Settings.MultipleInstances=2
                        $taskdefinition.Settings.WakeToRun=$true
                        $triggers = $TaskDefinition.Triggers
                        $trigger = $triggers.Create(1) # Creates a "One time" trigger
                        $trigger.StartBoundary = $TaskStartTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
                        $time_interval=New-TimeSpan -Minutes $interval
                        $time_interval=$time_interval.TotalSeconds
                        $trigger.Repetition.Interval= "PT"+"$time_interval"+"S"
                        $trigger.Enabled = $true
                        $TaskDefinition.Principal.RunLevel =1
                        $Action = $TaskDefinition.Actions.Create(0)
                        $action.Path = "$TaskCommand"
                        $action.Arguments = "$TaskArg"
                        # In Task Definition,
                        #   6 indicates "the task will not execute when it is registered unless a time-based trigger causes it to execute on registration."
                        #   5 indicates "Indicates that a Local System, Local Service, or Network Service account is being used as a security context to run the task.In this case, its the SYSTEM"
                        $rootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("$TaskName",$TaskDefinition,6,"System",$null,5) | Out-Null
```

I have added the corresponding comments to create the task and the trigger accordingly.

**Alternative method** is to directly using Powershell like this :

```
Import-Module TaskScheduler $task = New-Task
$task.Settings.Hidden = $true
Add-TaskAction -Task $task -Path C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe –Arguments “-File C:\Users\mine\Desktop\LOL\test.ps1”
Add-TaskTrigger -Task $task -Daily -At “10:06”
Register-ScheduledJob –Name ”Monitor Group Management” -Task $task
```

**Direct Approach:**

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NonInteractive -File "C:\Users\mine\Desktop\LOL\test.ps1"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: how do i check the taskscheduler status?

Comment: Manually go to scheduler and click on the jobs to check it. That way you will get the proper message if it fails.